# Which one is Funami Yui's apartment room?

Tags: yuru-yuri

In Yuru Yuri San Hai! episode 6, there was power outage. Later, the building where Yui lives was shown.

[image: Yui's room?]

Which makes me think that (based on the center of the picture), Yui's room is the one on top right corner with the lights on. However, later on it was shown like this.

[image: Yui's room??]

Which one is Yui's room?

Comment: From which episode is the second screenshot?

Comment: Same episode as the first one.